# Groovy - How do I propagate Jenkins job environment variable to Bob class?

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have a Jenkins file that is used to run/trigger certain stages in my Jenkins job. In this file, I have included a when expression in some stages to only trigger when a certain job is running (as this Jenkins file is used for two Jenkins jobs):

```
stage('Sample stage') {
    when {
        expression {
            return env.JOB_NAME == job_a
    }
}
```

If job_a is running, then this stage will run. Otherwise it, will be skipped.

In this Jenkins file, I also have a class called BobCommand:

```
import groovy.transform.builder.Builder
import groovy.transform.builder.SimpleStrategy

@Builder(builderStrategy = SimpleStrategy, prefix = '')
class BobCommand {
    def bobImage = 'bob.2.0:latest'
    def envVars = [:]
    def needDockerSocket = false

    String toString() {
        def env = envVars
                .collect({ entry -> "-e ${entry.key}=\"${entry.value}\"" })
                .join(' ')

        def cmd = """\
            |docker run
            |--init
            |--rm
            |--workdir \${PWD}
            |--user \$(id -u):\$(id -g)
            |-v \${PWD}:\${PWD}
            |-v \${HOME}/.m2:\${HOME}/.m2
            |-v \${HOME}/.docker:\${HOME}/.docker
            |${needDockerSocket ? '-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock' : ''}
            |${env}
            |\$(for group in \$(id -G); do printf ' --group-add %s' "\$group"; done)
            |--group-add \$(stat -c '%g' /var/run/docker.sock)
            |${bobImage}
            |"""
        
            return cmd
                .stripMargin()           // remove indentation
                .replace('\n', ' ')      // join lines
                .replaceAll(/[ ]+/, ' ') // replace multiple spaces by one
    }
}
```

Due to how the jobs are setup and what pipelines the jobs are used in, I need a way to change the `cmd` depending on what job is running. I want to include a simple if statement that checks if job_a is running, use this `cmd` otherwise use another `cmd` version of the docker run command.

I have tried a few different things:

- At the top of my file, I have defined a bob variable whereby I have tried to include the JOB_NAME env var

  ```
  def bob = new BobCommand()
          .bobImage(defaultBobImage)
          .envVars([NAMESPACE: '${NAMESPACE}', JOB_NAME: env.JOB_NAME])
          .needDockerSocket(true)
          .toString()
  ```

  and then access it in my BobCommand class with env.JOB_NAME
- I have tried to define a new String variable `jobName` in my BobCommand class, and then in a stage in the pipeline I do `bob.jobName = env.JOB_NAME`
- I have tried to use `BobCommand.builder().jobName(env.JOB_NAME).build()`

Does anyone know where I am going wrong or what I'm trying to do is possible? If not, is there a better way to achieve what I want to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forgot to specify strategy `@Builder(builderStrategy=SimpleStrategy)`

```
import groovy.transform.ToString
import groovy.transform.builder.Builder
import groovy.transform.builder.SimpleStrategy

@Builder(builderStrategy=SimpleStrategy)
@ToString /*just for test*/
class BobCommand {
    def bobImage = 'bob.2.0:latest'
    def envVars = [:]
    def needDockerSocket = false
}

new BobCommand().setBobImage('iiii').setEnvVars(foo:'bar', xyz:'abc').toString()
// ->  BobCommand(iiii, [foo:bar, xyz:abc], false)
```

javadoc on simple strategy:
https://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/gapi/groovy/transform/builder/SimpleStrategy.html

Without specification the [DefaultStrategy](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/gapi/groovy/transform/builder/DefaultStrategy.html) used:

```
import groovy.transform.ToString
import groovy.transform.builder.Builder
import groovy.transform.builder.SimpleStrategy

@Builder
@ToString /*just for test*/
class BobCommand {
    def bobImage = 'bob.2.0:latest'
    def envVars = [:]
    def needDockerSocket = false
}

BobCommand.builder().bobImage('iiii').envVars(foo:'bar', xyz:'abc').build().toString()
// ->  BobCommand(iiii, [foo:bar, xyz:abc], false)
```

Comment: I have `@Builder(builderStrategy = SimpleStrategy, prefix = '')` already included



Can I just do `def bob = new BobCommand()     .bobImage(defaultBobImage).envVars([NAMESPACE:'${NAMESPACE}]).needDockerSocket(true).jobName(env.JOB_NAME).toString()` according to the link you sent?

Comment: that's correct.